# Singularity in the Expansion of Geodesic congruences

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

My question is regarding the following graph,
[image]

The $X$-axis is the $r$ coordinate of the $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ system, and the $Y$-axis is the expansion $\Theta$ of a congruence of weakly bound, timelike, radial geodesics. There is only a physical (curvature) singularity at $O$. However after some calculations, I obtained the graph above, where $\Theta$ is seen to diverge at a finite value. This is specifically for outgoing geodesics (invert the graph for ingoing geodesics)

**Question:**
What is the interpretation of this scenario **just** from the graph above?

My guess is that, outgoing radial geodesics all converge at the value $r = r_P$ (for the weakly bound condition) and can never go out to infinity. If this reasoning is correct, does this mean that a cloud of dust following such a congruence abruptly ends/stops at the boundary denoted by $r_p$ or a caustic is formed there, or is the behaviour of the dust something else?

Comment: Could $r_P$ be the turning point? So that particles reach this value and start falling back toward the center.

Comment: @A.V.S , I thought about that too, but does the expansion need to go to $-\infty$ for that? It seems apparently they are not connected. I am not sure at all. For reference (I will edit later) such singularities are observed in expansions of time-like radial geodesics of BTS type 2 spacetimes.

Comment: Does it *need* to go I am not sure, but it is certainly possible. Informally, the expansion is like $\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the 3-velocity (the projection of 4-velocity onto $t=\mathrm{const}$ slice) as a function of 3-coordinates. Near the turning point the velocity as a function of $r$ would behave like $v(r)\sim \sqrt{E-V(r)}\approx a \sqrt{r_P- r}$, so the expansion could go to $-∞$ because of $\partial v /\partial r$. (All this is of course assuming generic conditions and *good* behavior of metric near $r_P$).